# AWS API to create s3 bucket and add upload file in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am searching Rest API for the following things:

- To create an s3 bucket
- Upload file in the s3 bucket

I am having Access key and Secret access key of my account.
Can you please help me into this?

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) than to directly call a REST interface.

All SDKs provide methods for creating buckets and uploading files.

Comment: Yes, I have used AWS SDK but I want REST API to fulfill my issue. Can you please help me into this?

Comment: [Amazon S3 REST API Introduction - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the following API to create a bucket :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html

how we can get authorization string here to send request?

Comment: [Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version 4) - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html)

Comment: can you please give me an example to get authorization string. I am facing issue to understand above doc.

Comment: Feel free to create a new Question with your code and an explanation of the difficulty you are facing.